# Mapping function returning value

Tags: solidity, contract-development, addresses, mapping, keyword

Below is the code which I saw on Solidity official [site](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/types.html#mapping-types)

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.9.0;

contract MappingExample {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    function update(uint newBalance) public {
        balances[msg.sender] = newBalance;
    }
}

contract MappingUser {
    function f() public returns (uint) {
        MappingExample m = new MappingExample();
        m.update(100);            //       **LINE 1**
        return m.balances(address(this));         **LINE 2**
    }
}
```

What is `m.update(100)` is doing in contract ? I thought that it will be passing value 100 in the paramter `newBalance` in function `update` of contract `MappingExample`. But it is taking value from user.

Secondly , please explain to me what role does line 2 i.e  `m.balances(address(this))` have in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapping(address => uint) public balances;`

is a Map from an address to a number

```
address1 -> number
address2 -> number
...
```

Because it is public, Solidity will create a hidden function for you called balances, and will look like this `function balances(address addr) view returns (uint)` this function will return the stored value (number) for a given key (address)

The function `function update(uint newBalance) public` update this map by updating the value (number) for the key which is the caller (address)

**NOW**

MappingUser is a new contract that has a function `function f() public returns (uint)`

This function do the following:

- `MappingExample m = new MappingExample();` Deploy a new MappingExample Contract
- `m.update(100);` It sends a request to the new contract and calls the update function. WARNING the update function has `msg.sender` and in this case the caller of the update function is the `MappingUser` contract and not the user. so it basically changes the value in the map `address-of-MappingUser-contract -> 100`
- `return m.balances(address(this));` it calls hidden balances function and it gives its address (the address of `MappingUser` contract) as an argument. `address(this)` is the address of the `MappingUser` contract

Comment: Thank you very very much .So basically , does it mean that  `MappingUser` contract is just creating a entry in the mapping table and not doi ng anything else. Is it so ?

Comment: It deploy a new contract each time ‚f()‘ is called and add an entry to the map in the new deployed contract. This entry is <mapping-user-contract-address> to 100 @Brijesh